# Approximate 3 reals as corresponding integers with similar relationships

Tags: optimization

I have a complicated algorithm that calculates 3 values, $\text{Low} \lt \text{High} \lt \text{Total}$ as real values (actually double-precision floating point) and I need to approximate them as 3 integers ($\text{32-bit} \implies \text{value} \in \mathopen{[}0, 2^{32}-1\mathclose{]}$)

$$
\begin{align}
\text{IntLow} & \approx \text{Low}\\
\text{IntTotal} & \approx \text{Total}\\
\text{IntCount} & \approx \text{High} - \text{Low}\\
\text{IntCount} + \text{IntLow} & \approx \text{High}\\
\end{align}
$$

The integer values need to maintain the following relationships as closely as possible. For convenence, let $\text{IntHigh} ≝ \text{IntCount} + \text{IntLow}$
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{\text{Low}}{\text{High}} & \approx \frac{\text{IntLow}}{\text{IntHigh}}\\[6pt]
\frac{\text{Low}}{\text{Total}} & \approx \frac{\text{IntLow}}{\text{IntTotal}}\\[6pt]
\frac{\text{High}}{\text{Total}} & \approx \frac{\text{IntHigh}}{\text{IntTotal}}\\[6pt]
\frac{\text{High} - \text{Low}}{\text{Total}} & \approx \frac{\text{IntCount}}{\text{IntTotal}}
\end{align}
$$

How can this minimization problem best be solved?

Below is an explanation of my current approach.

---

My current approach is to iterate:
$$
\begin{align}
\text{IntLow} & ≔ \operatorname{floor}\left(\text{Low} \times \text{Multiplier}\right)\\
\text{IntCount} & ≔ \operatorname{floor}\left((\text{High} - \text{Low}) \times \text{Multiplier}\right)\\
\text{IntTotal} & ≔ \operatorname{floor}\left(\text{Total} \times \text{Multiplier}\right)
\end{align}
$$
and compute the sum of absolute differences between the fractions for a multiplier that is a positive power of two. Then I refine the best found multiplier by trying the two multipliers $(\text{multiplier} \times 2^{1/2^x})$ and $(\text{multiplier} \div 2^{1/2^x})$ for $x \in \mathopen{[}1, 32\mathclose{]}$ and update the best multiplier after each 'round' as appropriate. This works, but it requires a lot of floating point division, and it seems likely there is a better way than 'brute forcing' the bits of the multiplier.

Comment: I did a few corrections to your MathJax coding; maybe that will tell you what to do with the rest. Note the difference between $32{-}bit$ and $32\text{-bit}$, not only in the lack of italics but also in that the hyphen looks like a hyphen. Using an asterisk for ordinary multiplication in MathJax or LaTeX or the like is like being an invited guest at a state dinner hosted by the Queen at Buckingham Palace and eating mashed potatoes by shoving your face into the plate when silverware is available.

Comment: Thank you for you corrections. I believe I have propagated them everywhere.